# Custom Fields in order xml

Tags: magento-1.8, orders, xml

Hi I have added a custom field on checkout page and it show in order also. But how can I actualy get it from the order in xml file. I already have taken in phtml with this part of code, `<?php $order_ref = $this->htmlEscape($this->getOrder()->getssn());?>`.
The module I have used is on this page http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-add-custom-fields-checkout-page.

And also I already have tried with previous code to get in xml but it doesn't work any proposition or help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The row information that is exported to xml via the admin's order section is built from the function `_getExportHeaders` in the file `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid`.

```
protected function _getExportHeaders()
{
    $row = array();
    foreach ($this->_columns as $column) {
        if (!$column->getIsSystem()) {
            $row[] = $column->getExportHeader();
        }
    }
    return $row;
}
```

As you can see here is will add all items in `$this->columns` that are not system attributes. These columns are set-up as part of the grid itself, so simply speaking if the attribute is shown on the sales order grid and it is not a system attribute then it will be exported as part of the xml file.

These columns are added to the grid via `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid->_prepareColumns`.